# A curried function that filters by symbol is unable to get a compatible function implementation in Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, iterator, async-iterator

I've got a curried batching function that returns an Iterable. If you call it with a sync `Iterable` you get a sync `Iterable`, if you give an `AsyncIterable` you get an `AsyncIterable`. But can't for the life of me get the sync overload to be accepted by the function implementation.

This particular def is what's giving an error

```
export function batch(size: number): <T>(curriedIterable: Iterable<T>) => IterableIterator<T[]>
```

Here's all the code

```
async function* _batch<T>(size: number, iterable: AsyncIterable<T>) {
  let dataBatch: T[] = []
  for await (const data of iterable) {
    dataBatch.push(data)
    if (dataBatch.length === size) {
      yield dataBatch
      dataBatch = []
    }
  }
  if (dataBatch.length > 0) {
    yield dataBatch
  }
}

function* _syncBatch<T>(size: number, iterable: Iterable<T>) {
  let dataBatch: T[] = []
  for (const data of iterable) {
    dataBatch.push(data)
    if (dataBatch.length === size) {
      yield dataBatch
      dataBatch = []
    }
  }
  if (dataBatch.length > 0) {
    yield dataBatch
  }
}

export function batch(size: number): <T>(curriedIterable: AsyncIterable<T>) => AsyncIterableIterator<T[]>
export function batch<T>(size: number, iterable: AsyncIterable<T>): AsyncIterableIterator<T[]>
export function batch(size: number): <T>(curriedIterable: Iterable<T>) => IterableIterator<T[]>
export function batch<T>(size: number, iterable: Iterable<T>): IterableIterator<T[]>
export function batch<T>(size: number, iterable?: Iterable<T> | AsyncIterable<T>) {
  if (iterable === undefined) {
    return curriedIterable => batch(size, curriedIterable)
  }
  if (iterable[Symbol.asyncIterator]) {
    return _batch(size, iterable as AsyncIterable<T>)
  }
  return _syncBatch(size, iterable as Iterable<T>)
}
```

Comment: It isn't that particular def that is giving you problems. Rather, its that you are trying to use *both* that def and the async def.

Answer (score 1):

I have duplicate definitions for `function batch(size: number):` when I need overloaded defs for it's return function. The following solves that.

```
export function batch(size: number): {
  <T>(curriedIterable: AsyncIterable<T>): AsyncIterableIterator<T[]>
  <T>(curriedIterable: Iterable<T>): IterableIterator<T[]>
}
export function batch<T>(size: number, iterable: AsyncIterable<T>): AsyncIterableIterator<T[]>
export function batch<T>(size: number, iterable: Iterable<T>): IterableIterator<T[]>
```

This types out alright.